# Close as a duplicate on mobile: Lots of Vertical Scrolling

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, mobile-web, usability

Attempting to use the site with a Nexus 4.  I came across a question that was a duplicate, so I found the dupe and voted to close.

The only problem:  **the button is at the bottom of the modal.**  While in mobile view, that means lots of painful scrolling all the way through the question *and* its answers.

On the normal site this isn't an issue:

[image: This is normal and okay - you don't have to scroll through the question.]

...but on the mobile site...

[image: It's all the way in the bottom corner!]

Here's an example:

[image]

This definitely affects usability while on mobile.

Comment: Yes! I am on mobile a lot, and this bugs me, but I keep forgetting to report it! Also; I wish I could do such pretty freehand...

Comment: I added an example about the scrolling nightmare. This needs to be fixed—it's excruciating.

Comment: My proposed solution to this is [just don't show the answers at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192649/dont-show-answers-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate-on-mobile).

Comment: @Sklivvz Oh come on, how is this not a (usability) bug? Compare it to the desktop version — the window for the duplicate question is height-limited and it doesn't **require** you to scroll all the way to the bottom just to find the link.

Comment: Strongly agree that this is a bug not a feature request. The mobile skin is missing a suitable implementation of this existing feature, so loads one that is not fit for purpose.

Comment: @IMSoP bug is when the intended behavior is not working as expected. In this case, the position of the button and the scrolling is the intended behavior. No bug here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'd be surprised if the position of the button is intended behaviour rather than a side-effect of implementation. In the desktop UI, the close button is visible at all times, with no scrolling required. The mobile UI appears to be identical, but without the additional scrollbar; the button is in the same place, but now you have to scroll miles to reach it.

Comment: @IMSoP the developer who is writing the code changed from bug to feature request so it's all the proof we need. Not saying I support this and I also want it fixed, just explaining.

Comment: As far as I understand correctly after the responsive interface will be implemented, the mobile web version will die.

Comment: @alexolut:  Back when this was posted, there was no such thing as a "responsive" interface for SO.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376287/make-closing-as-duplicate-easier-on-mobile-web

Comment: @Script47:  This bug report predates that one by **five *years***.

Comment: @Makoto I dun goofed on the wording. I meant that a dupe of *this* question has just been posted on meta SO and wanted to link it.

Answer (score 2):

You should give the new responsive design for mobile a try. It fixes a lot of these annoying bugs that have been bothering us for a long time (while at the same time creating some, but overall it is better).

You can enable the responsive design by clicking `full site` in the page footer.

Then it looks like this:

> [image]

<sup>In a response to [a similar post on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376287/993547), I gave this answer. It applies to MSE, and other sites in the network too, so reposting here.</sup>