# Attempting to close as duplicate on mobile unleashes chaos

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, design, mobile-web

Voting to close as duplicate on mobile is pretty painful with the recent changes to the duplicate selection dialog, especially due to [vertical scrolling, as mentioned elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171199/close-as-a-duplicate-on-mobile-lots-of-vertical-scrolling).

However, at least on iOS, it's even worse than that. Pasting in a duplicate link to the overly-wide text field causes all sorts of crazy horizontal scrolling as well:

[image: horizontally-scrolled mobile close dialog]

You'll also note that the OP's user card is encroaching on the question tags' personal space. Similarly, selecting a duplicate via direct link or through one of the options in the dialog causes crowding to the left, smushing the title up against the "similiar/back to questions" link and cramping the "votes" text's style:

[image: cramped information in mobile close dialog]

I know that there's only so much space to work with on mobile, but at the moment it feels like this just has been overlooked. Presumably with some slight style tweaking, a lot of these more quirky behaviours could be avoided.

Finally – perhaps the most important issue of all – there's no space between "Closing" and the > sign:

[image: lack of space between closing text and >]

Comment: I am picturing people running in all directions and screaming. I have a very manly scream, in case you are interested in knowing.