# VTC as a duplicate doesn't really work on a mobile phone

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, mobile-web

So, when I try to VTC as a duplicate on a mobile phone, it is very difficult to complete the process.  Clicking on the question often links to the duplicate, and scrolling to find the 'Vote to Make a duplicate' is problemmatic at best.

Is there a way, that on mobile phones, the click throughs could be made smaller and the amt of text in the question be minimized?

As is, the experience is almost unusable.

Comment: IIRC this is a known issue. Lemmie trawl MSO

Comment: See also: [Attempting to close as duplicate on mobile unleashes chaos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173303)