# Mobile: unusable Close as Duplicate dialog

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, mobile-web, usability

I can understand how it's useful to see exactly which question you are nominating as the original, non-duplicate one when voting to close a question as an exact duplicate, but this presupposes that you have a screen which is large enough to accommodate this information, and crumbles entirely e.g. on my iPhone.

The content is presented in a JavaScript frame which cannot easily be resized, scaled, zoomed, or otherwise manipulated.  After a while, you get used to just scrolling way, wayyyy down to the Vote button real quickly (and, ideally, check that you really have the right question in a separate browser tab, where you have proper UI controls for scrolling, zooming, etc).  Of course, if both the duplicate and the original question are long, it's very easy to whizz past the button, and end up scrolling back and forth quite a bit just to locate it.

Finding button: [image: Finding Vote button]

At first, when you paste the URL to nominate the original which this is a duplicate of, if the URL is long enough, you basically only see the tail of the URL, and nothing else:

Nominating: [image: Nominating]

You have to scroll left to see even the right margin of the actual content.  This further adds to the frustration (but as noted in a comment, there is a workaround for this).

I'm not sure how exactly this should be fixed.  I guess you probably don't want to revert back to the old, less informative design, even though that was much less disruptive on mobile devices.  Maybe a more compact representation would be possible?  Maybe just moving the "Vote to close" button up high would be enough alleviate the aggravation?

Comment: As workarroung I suggest either copying only the short url (see share button under the post) or even just the number.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: thanks for the tip, it helps a little, but the far scrolling to the right is not the main problem here, although it certainly adds to the frustration.  Thanks for your comment, too; I refactored the text to highlight that the modality of the presentation is really the main problem.

Comment: @tripleee what is the difference between this question and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196014/mobile-close-as-duplicate-dialog-wont-close.both have been asked by you only

Comment: @NetStarter: They are different, did you read them both?  The other question is probably a trivial bug, whereas this requires some serious redesign.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173303/attempting-to-close-as-duplicate-on-mobile-unleashes-chaos is possibly a duplicate, but given its sensationalist style and muddy argumentation, I hesitate to mark this one as a duplicate, and am too humble to nominate duplication in the other direction.

Comment: @tripleee +1 ok got your point,sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: This is now moot, as the dialog was changed in the "responsive" revamp. It has a slew of other problems, but not this one.

Comment: However, this _is_ a cross-site duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376287/make-closing-as-duplicate-easier-on-mobile-web