# Mobile: Close as Duplicate dialog won't close

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, mobile-web, usability

If you change your mind about closing a question as a duplicate (maybe because you meant to vote to close, but for a different reason, and just clicked the wrong option in the first dialog) the mobile interface won't easily close.

When you click the big white X in a red ball in the upper right corner, the box flickers, so you know the click was registered, but it doesn't close.  I often find myself repeating this a dozen times before it finally takes.

Comment: This is on IOS using Grazing (rather than the abysmal Mobile Safari) so maybe it's just a bug with my browser.  I was unable to repro in Safari just now.  Also tried the mobile view in Firefox on Windows, but couldn't repro there, either.

Comment: This is most definitely not a duplicate, though I don't think I have recently been able to repro this one.