# Don't show answers when voting to close as duplicate on mobile

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, mobile-web

This originally started bothering me when voting to close as duplicate of a question which had deleted answers. I thought to myself, "Why on Earth am I being shown the deleted answers for this?" Why do I want to scroll through a bunch of deleted content that the average user won't even see when they get there?

After dealing with it more, it really doesn't seem clear to me why it loads answers at all. A mobile device just isn't friendly enough to be loading extremely long blocks of text like this. The question itself will suffice. If I wa t to see the answers, I can go to the question itself. Seriously, you try to close a question as a duplicate of the Formatting Sandbox on the mobile layout, see where that gets you...

Can the answers please be removed from the vote to close as duplicate dialog on the mobile layout?

Comment: Or at least move the confirm button to be before the answer/post

Comment: If I like DFinoff's idea, but not the original request, should I downvote? I do like DFinoff's idea.

Comment: @FDinoff Well then you run into the problem of people not looking over the question before they're able to submit their vote. Kind of like putting the "I Accept" button above the terms of service rather than below.

Comment: Ah yes please. Especially for some of the obvious meta duplicates with a lot of answers this is rather annoying.

Comment: I would vote to close it as that @Aditya, but it requires too much scrolling.

Comment: I was originally thinking below the question but before the answers. However changed it to answer/post because people might not find it is you stick it in the middle. I guess you could put it on the page twice. Once right after the question and one right after all the answers (where it currently is)